# Printing definitions of functions/classes in ghci with lambdabot

Tags: haskell, ghci, lambdabot

How can I view the source definitions in ghci (with lambdabot [2.5 GHCi on Acid](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/GHCi#GHCi_on_Acid)) of functions/classes etc defined in my project or cabal dependencies?
For example suppose I have :

```
module Main where
import System.Random

gen = (random (mkStdGen 0)) :: (Bool,StdGen)

myadd :: Int -> Int
myadd x = 2 * x

main = do
  print "finished"
```

Then I can get information on `myadd` and `random` but I cannot print the source. Here is what I can do in ghci (with lambdabot) :

```
*Main GOA> :src foldr
 foldr f z []     = z
foldr f z (x:xs) = f x (foldr f z xs)
*Main GOA> :i myadd
myadd :: Int -> Int     -- Defined at test.hs:7:1
*Main GOA> :src myadd
 Source not found. I don't think I can be your friend on Facebook anymore.
*Main GOA> :i random
class Random a where
  ...
  random :: RandomGen g => g -> (a, g)
  ...
    -- Defined in ‘System.Random’
*Main GOA> :src random
 Source not found. Listen, broccoli brains, I don't have time to listen to this trash.
```

lambdabot seems to be able to print the definitions of `foldr` but not functions defined in 
the project (`myadd`) or functions in the cabal depedencies (`random`).

Is it possible for me to print out the definitions of things like `myadd` and `random`, using some feature of lambdabot? I know you can use Hoogle for `random` but I want to specifically know if there is any way to use ghci or lambdabot to print out the source definitions.

[EDIT]

Since posting I discovered [Emacs/Inferior Haskell processes](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Emacs/Inferior_Haskell_processes) and some of the functionality theirin seems to achieve some of the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lambdabot's `src` can't do this. It is based on a short list of function definitions that ships with lambdabot itself, cf. https://github.com/mokus0/lambdabot/blob/master/lambdabot/State/source. Consequently it sometimes lies, for example `foldr` is currently defined in ghc's libraries as

```
foldr k z = go
      where
        go []     = z
        go (y:ys) = y `k` go ys
```